# How to remove the first and last portion of a string in Python?

Tags: python

How can i cut from such a string (json) everything before and including the **first** `[` and everything behind and including the **last** `]` with Python?

```
{
    "Customers": [
        {
           "cID": "w2-502952",
           "soldToId": "34124"
        },
        ...
        ...
    ],
        "status": {
        "success": true,
        "message": "Customers: 560",
        "ErrorCode": ""
    }
}
```

I want to have at least only

```
{
"cID" : "w2-502952",
"soldToId" : "34124",
}
...
...
```

Comment: why are you treating it like a string? Just access that element when you need it

Comment: You have to parse the JSON to do it safely, so you may as well use `json.loads` to get an object, extract the desired value, then re-encode it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String manipulation is *not* the way to do this. You should parse your JSON into Python and extract the relevant data using normal data structure access.

```
obj = json.loads(data)
relevant_data = obj["Customers"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do to it otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @Daniel Rosman answer, if you want all the `list` from `JSON`.

```
result = []
obj = json.loads(data)

for value in obj.values():
    if isinstance(value, list):
        result.append(*value)
```

Comment: This is also correct, but due to the question the answer which best fits is Daniels answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this via string manipulation (which I don't recommend), you can do it this way:

```
start = s.find('[') + 1
finish = s.find(']')
inner = s[start : finish]
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that Daniel's answer is the absolute best way to go, if you *must* use string splitting, you can try `.find()`

```
string = #however you are loading this json text into a string

start = string.find('[')
end = string.find(']')
customers = string[start:end]
print(customers)
```

output will be everything between the `[` and `]` braces.